# How can I display this text with z-index?

Tags: html, css

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fvaFN/1/) code :

```
<div class="header_photo">
    <div class="header_inside">
        <div class="header_text">
            Text
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="header_photo_transparent">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

.header_inside
{
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    display: block; 
    width: 975px; 
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; 
    z-index: 4; 
    position: absolute;
}

.header_text
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:15px;
    width:500px;
    z-index:201;     
    left:370px;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:13px;
}

.header_photo_transparent
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:960px;
    height:64px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index:100;
}
```

and I'd like to display the string Text over the red background, without :

1. changing the z-index of header_photo_transparent;
2. without removing position:absolute from header_inside

In fact I don't see the string Text.

Why this behaviour? And how can I fix this trouble?

Comment: What behavior?  What trouble?  Please describe.

Comment: Updated the question. I don't see the Text string :)

Comment: Your text is inside a container with z=4 and the red background element is z=100... red element will be **over** text container... this is the exact expected behavior.

Comment: why don't you want to change the z-index?

Comment: I'm pulling out of this one... the code in the JSFiddle and within the OP have both been changed since I started looking into it.  I'm not posting an answer that's going to be quickly rendered invalid by such undocumented edits.

Comment: Those values are generated by a jQuery plugins, that's why I can't change them. -2?

Comment: @Sparky672 if I put z-index from 4 to 400 for example, nothing change...! The problem is that absolute I think..

Comment: @Sparky672 : and the text container is z-index 201...more than 100...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Z-index is not at fault, just remove the z-index and use the positioning. The positioning is out, not the layers.

http://jsfiddle.net/zaSKZ/1/

Comment: It's now measuring from the top, so with jsfiddle, it depends on your viewport height. My point remains, however, you don't need z-index.